# I stuck a circle to my cursor and when I move it fast it seems like the circle cuts off

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was wondering how I could fix this? Whenever I move my mouse quick or just move it overall it seems like the circle cuts in half, I want it to be a full circle when moving fast.

```js
$(document).ready(
  () => {
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var xp = 0;
    var yp = 0;
    $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
      $("#cursor").css("left", event.pageX - 25);
      $("#cursor").css("top", event.pageY - 25);
      $("#cursor").css("display", "block");
      //console.log("worked");
    });
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue (I am on a reasonably powerful laptop using Edge Windows10). What browser/OS are you using and with what hardware? It sounds as though you may need to do some throttling if your system cannot keep up.

Comment: Yep, it also works fine for me!